# How to use custom fast scroll with activity containing a Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

Since using a toolbar requires a theme to be set, (`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`), I'm not sure on know on what theme needs to be used because a custom fast scroll thumb requires a theme to be set. In my case, I've used `android:theme="@style/GreenTheme"` but I still need to a toolbar for the activity. How can this be achieved?

**Mainfest file (activity declaration)**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/main_activity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

**styles.xml (declaration of fast scroll)**

```
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fastscrollpreview_green</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscrollthumb_green</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

**List view with fast scroll**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

**ActivityMain.xml**
***use the toolbar and then use the list view and inside the list add the layout(any layout ) and the   you can use more view inside a list***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
         android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_white" >
           <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          <Button
                    android:id="@+id/clxbtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Close" />

   </LinearLayout>
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout >
```